# how to launch gnome apps with su permissions?

Tags: python, gnome, rpm

I have a python app I want to distribute as an rpm.  The app requires talking to usb devices.  To talk to usb devices, I need sudo privileges (or some type of permission I've yet to learn about).

Unfortunately, my app fails to launch from the gnome application menu with a .desktop file when I specify running as sudo.

***won't even launch***

EXEC=sudo python /usr/bin/app_launcher.py %f

***launches, but no usb***

EXEC=python /usr/bin/app_launcher.py %f

As there is no where for the user to even enter their password, *I am pretty sure this is not even the right approach*.  What to do?

http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html

Comment: Did you tried [gksu](http://live.gnome.org/gksu)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `gksudo`, not `sudo`. It's that full-screen modal dialog that prompts for your password:

```
EXEC=gksudo python /usr/bin/app_launcher.py %f
```

Comment: Alas, when I launch now I get "Failed to execute child process "gksudo" (No such file or directory).  Researching now...

Comment: Try `gksu`. What distro are you doing this with?